# How to remove Cyclomatic complexcity

Tags: java, sonarlint

I am getting Cyclomatic complexity (`The Cyclomatic Complexity of this method "mapRow" is 13 which is greater than 10 authorized`) from below code :

```
public RedemptionReport mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {        
        RedemptionReport redemptionReport = new RedemptionReport();
        redemptionReport.setRedeemDate(rs.getString(1));
        redemptionReport.setCashierID(rs.getString(2) != null? rs.getString(2) : "");
        redemptionReport.setTillNo(rs.getString(3) != null? rs.getString(3) : "");
        redemptionReport.setReferenceNumber(rs.getString(4) != null? rs.getString(4) : "");
        redemptionReport.setTransactionNumber(rs.getString(5) != null? rs.getString(5) : "");
        redemptionReport.setRedemptionAmount(rs.getString(6) != null? rs.getString(6) : "0");
        redemptionReport.setNetBillValues(rs.getString(7) != null? rs.getString(7) : "0");
        redemptionReport.setStoreCode(rs.getString(8) != null? rs.getString(8) : "");
        redemptionReport.setCardNumber(rs.getString(9) != null? rs.getString(9) : "");
        redemptionReport.setCardType(rs.getString(10) != null? rs.getString(10) : "");
        redemptionReport.setStoreDesc(rs.getString(11) != null? rs.getString(11) : "");
        redemptionReport.setZoneDesc(rs.getString(12) != null? rs.getString(12) : "");
        redemptionReport.setMobileNo(rs.getString(13) != null? rs.getString(13) : "");
        redemptionReport.setSchemeName(rs.getString(14));
        return redemptionReport;
    }
```

How to remove this complexity from the above code?

Comment: create a method like `getStringValue(rs.getString (13));`

Comment: or just set the values and change all null values in one hit later

Answer (score 2):

Create a method that will encapsulate the ternary operator, e.g.:

```
private String get(String val, String def) {
    return val != null ? val : def
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
private String get(String val) {
    return val != null ? val : ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

override RedemptionReport's setters. This should belong to domain class as the default values makes sense only in RedemptionReport class.
Pass "rs.getString(x)"  value to the setter method.

Answer (score 1):

```
public RedemptionReport mapRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {        
        RedemptionReport redemptionReport = new RedemptionReport();
        redemptionReport.setRedeemDate(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(1)));
        redemptionReport.setCashierID(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(2)));
        redemptionReport.setTillNo(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(3)));
        redemptionReport.setReferenceNumber(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(4)));
        redemptionReport.setTransactionNumber(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(5)));
        redemptionReport.setRedemptionAmount(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(6)));
        redemptionReport.setNetBillValues(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(7)));
        redemptionReport.setStoreCode(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(8)));
        redemptionReport.setCardNumber(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(9)));
        redemptionReport.setCardType(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(10)));
        redemptionReport.setStoreDesc(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(11)));
        redemptionReport.setZoneDesc(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(12)));
        redemptionReport.setMobileNo(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(13)));
        redemptionReport.setSchemeName(this.getResultFromResultSet(rs.getString(14)));

return redemptionReport;
    }
```

define another private message to do such work(Null Check and return default value).

```
private String getResultFromResultSet(String val){
        return val != null ? val : "";
}
```